# Choose ID With Contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to edit controls with contextmenu. When i click right click, i need get menu id number, but it's writting only first menu id. How can i fix it?

```
$('#kutu').bind('contextmenu',function(e){
        var $cmenu = $(this).next();
        var ix = $(this).parent().find("h1").parent().find("div").html();
        $("#bilgiler").html(ix);
        $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css({left : '0px', top : '0px',position: 'absolute', width:                                                   '100%', height: '100%', zIndex: '100' }).click(function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $cmenu.hide();
        }).bind('contextmenu' , function(){return false;}).appendTo(document.body);
        $(this).next().css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY-15, zIndex: '101' }).show();

        return false;
         });
```

And My PHP menu codes..

```
echo '<H1 class="ustBaslik" id="fakulteBilgileriH1">';
    echo '<img src="../resimler/bolge.png" alt="" /> '.$cek["KategoriIsmi"].$cek["KategoriID"];
    echo '<div style="display:none">'.$cek["KategoriID"].'</div></H1>';
```

For Test: http://jsfiddle.net/6KdKC/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script to:

```
$('#kutu h1').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    var $cmenu = $(this).parent().next();
    var ix = $(this).find('div').html();
    $("#bilgiler").html(ix);
    $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css({
        left : '0px'
        , top : '0px'
        , position: 'absolute'
        , width: '100%'
        , height: '100%'
        , zIndex: '100'
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $cmenu.hide();
    }).bind('contextmenu', function(){
        return false;
    }).appendTo(document.body);
    $cmenu.css({
        left: e.pageX
        , top: e.pageY - 15
        , zIndex: '101'
    }).show();
    return false;
});
```

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KdKC/5/).